# It's that possible in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Help, how can I make this to "Correct" true without change the condition.
Just changing the Variable value.
In JavaScript

```
         Let Variable;
\*
         If(Variable == 1 && Variable == 2 && Variable == 3)
             Console.log("Correct");
           else
           Console.log("Incorrect");

*\
```

Comment: `Let Variable;` will throw a `SyntaxError`, and `Console.log` will throw `Console is not defined`

Comment: `If` is also not valid-- you want `if` -- remember that JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Answer (score -1):

Use this given below code, it's working as per your logic

```
let variable;
if(variable == 1 && variable == 2 && variable == 3) {
    console.log("Correct");
} else {
  console.log("Incorrect");
}
```

Note: given condition never correct because one variable only hold one value use or condition (||).

```
let variable;
if(variable == 1 || variable == 2 || variable == 3) {
    console.log("Correct");
} else {
  console.log("Incorrect");
}
```

Comment: It's possible I did it, I created an object

Comment: True, if u create object then it work, but not for normal variable.